# Can I register for ancestry.co.uk if I live somewhere else?

Tags: ancestry.com

Is it possible to register for an ancestry.co.uk account if I live in a different country? What would be the benefit of doing so? Would my tree connect better to UK member trees?

I can't afford the world subscription right now, so am wondering if my lapsed account could be changed to a UK subscription instead of the Canadian one I had last year.

Comment: As an aside I had no trouble opening and using my FindMyPast registration in the UK rather than Australia, except for it occasionally noticing that I am from there and asking me if I want to switch to it.

Comment: @PolyGeo Good to know. I was wondering if every time I was on the site it would ask me if I'd like to go to ancestry.ca ...Totally annoying!

Comment: Once you have a subscription to another ancestry site, the messages to switch sites stop. Also the default settings in search will change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can subscribe to Ancestry.co.uk from anywhere in the world, on either a monthly or annual basis.

Simply go to the [Ancestry.co.uk subscription page](http://www.ancestry.co.uk/cs/offers/subscribe).

You will be charged in Pounds Sterling, which may incur a small exchange fee if using a credit card in a foreign currency.

You should be able to log-in with the same username and password you use for Ancestry.ca. There is no benefit in creating a new username and password on the Ancestry.uk site.

With a UK subscription, there will be no benefit in connecting better to UK member trees, as all Public Member Trees from the Ancestry subsidiaries are in the same database.

Comment: I think the same is true of any of the ancestry country sites. (I've subscribed to the US site instead of the Canadian one for many years). Each site does require a separate registration (which allows you to take advantage of special promotions that may be specific to a country site), but you can use the same user name & password every time. There used to be a discount if you participated substantially in indexing records, but that was only applied to the site in your country of residence.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by requires "a separate registration". Of course you have to purchase a subscription on the relevant site, but you only need to register an account (username/password) once for all sites.

Comment: You're both right -- you can use the same username and password across all the sites and have access to your tree, etc. -- but each site has separate site preferences and requires its own signups for email newsletters and alerts.